# Unable to show the selected item in the Wp7 Listpicker control

Tags: windows-phone-7, listpicker

Basically i am trying to pull the contacts from the phone and showing them in the Listpicker control for a feature in my app. I have two Listpickers, one for name of contacts list and the other showing the list of phonenumbers for the chosen contact.

Here is my code:

```
//Declarations

ContactsSearchEventArgs e1;
String SelectedName;
String SelectedNumber;
List<string> contacts = new List<string>();
List<string> phnum = new List<string>();


 public AddressBook() // Constructor 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Contacts contacts = new Contacts();
        contacts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(contacts_SearchCompleted);
        contacts.SearchAsync(string.Empty,FilterKind.None,null);            
    }

 void contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e) 
    {          
       e1 = e;

            foreach (var result in e.Results)
            {        

                if (result.PhoneNumbers.Count() != 0)
                {

                    contacts.Add(result.DisplayName.ToString());
                }                      

            }

        Namelist.ItemsSource = contacts; 

    }

 private void Namelist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedName = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem.ToString();
        phnum.Clear();            
        foreach (var result in e1.Results)
        {
            if (SelectedName == result.DisplayName)
            {

                phnum.Add(result.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault().ToString());

            }
        }

        Numbers.ItemsSource = phnum;            
    }

private void Numbers_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        SelectedNumber = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem.ToString();

    }
```

Am able to populate the Numberlist with phonenumbers for the chosen name at the Listpicker background, but the number is not showing up in the front. I think Numbers_SelectionChanged() event is called only one time when the page loads and am not seeing it triggerd when i change the contact list. Anyone has an idea of where am going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

If you change 
     `List<string>`
To
     `ObservableCollection<string>`
this should work.

Also then you only need to set the ItemSource once, in Xaml or you constructor.

But you may run into another issue with the November 2011 Toolkit and ListPicker.

See more [in thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032882/binding-listpicker-selectedindex-problem).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with ObservableCollection too..but it is still the same. Also i don't think this is with the Nov 2011 Listpicker issue because its working fine in other pages.

Comment: That doesn't work because he is not creating a binding between the ItemsSource and the collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Namelist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{  
    SelectedName = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem.ToString();
    phnum =  new List<string>();   // Changed instead of phnum.Clear()            
    foreach (var result in e1.Results)
    {
        if (SelectedName == result.DisplayName)
        {

            phnum.Add(result.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault().ToString());

        }
    }

    Numbers.ItemsSource = phnum;            
}
```

This works !!. While debugging i found its phnum.Clear() giving a problem. So i thought to create a new instance of phnum list for selected contact.